# ClickOnce Update Running App

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I am trying to get my head around how to keep an app, that is running, up to date with the clickonce version...

My app needs to run 24 hours a day, but, when I roll out an update, I want the software to notice that there is an update, update itself, and restart the new version.

I cannot work out if this is possible?

Any hints/tips would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

Comment: Did you try to call the update routine of ClickOnce in your code somewhere? Just put this call into a timer with 24h interval and you should be done here.

Answer (score 1):

We are using MAGE from the console to automate generation of application and deployment menifests.  Unfortunately, its API is not allowing us to do what you are asking.  So we automated manifest generation using Powershell.  First it runs mage to generate the manifest.  Then it opens the generate xml file and modifies it a bit, then it signs it.

The goal of this manifest massaging is to make the  tag look like this:

```
<deployment install="true" trustURLParameters="true" mapFileExtensions="true" minimumRequiredVersion="1.0.0.1140">
<subscription>
    <update>
        <beforeApplicationStartup />
    </update>
</subscription>
```

Let's go through it.

1. install=true: this means that the application will be installed.  Once installed, the app can run from the local hard-drive without having to download itself from the web again.
2. trustURLParameters=true: we have code which captures the querystring and uses parameters to alter app behavior
3. mapFileExtensions=true: We change all non-manifest filenames, adding the .deploy at the end of their names to ensure that client's web filters which normally block executables and other known binaries will pass these files through.  Setting this attribute tells clickonce to rename files back
4. minimumRequiredVersion="1.0.0.1140".  This is the important one.  Becuase the update happens before application starts, every time you launch the app, even from the local PC, it will check for the update online.  If the manifest was upgraded to newer version, the app will update itself and then launch.

The inner elements of the  element tell the app to update itself every time it launches.  If the server is down, the update will fail, but the app will run from the local PC, because it's installed.

More on this element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7050f3w.aspx

Word of caution.  Never go back on the version.  The version number is meaningfull.  Once you reach a certain number, like 5, never go back to 4 or the app will fail to run.   This is important if you consider to deploy apps on the web server using symlinks.  You may think that creating a "prod" link and pointing it to version 5 will enable you a quick rollback to version 4 if version 5 is buggy.  Not the case.  You'll need to build version 6 with either a bug fix or same code as version 4.

Once you get your deployment to work, use the ClickOnce APIs in your app to check for updates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Note this call:

```
Application.Restart();
```

You'll need to pull in the WinForms library for this to work, but it works well.